# The speed of time

Tags: gravity, visible-light, acoustics, time

If the speed of light is 14,545.075 x the speed of sound, could the speed of time (and/or gravity) be 'something' like that times the speed of light, say 2,705,384,023.877 m.p.s? (Sonic boom > optic boom (whan objects APPEAR to approach infinite mass) > time boom)? Or must it all simply be (OR DOES IT ALL JUST APPEAR TO BE) only relative to light itself (time APPEARS to slow down as an object approaches the speed of light)? Does a potential speed of light trap alter our perceptions?  And how about - a speed of gravity (cause and effect)? How are time and gravity related, somehow?

Comment: the speed of time is always one second per second.

Comment: What do you mean by the speed of time?

Comment: There is no such thing as *the speed of time*. Could you clarify what you mean by this phrase?

Comment: OP keeps editing his post, the questions are kind of a moving target (but none very coherent).

Comment: *the speed of light is … times the speed of sound“. No, it isn’t. Speed of light is a constant, while the speed of sound varies depending on the medium and current circumstances, e.g. the density or temperature of air.

Answer (score 2):

> Are time and gravity the same thing?

No, they are not.

> Could there be a speed of gravity (cause and effect)?

Gravitational waves travel at the same speed as light. In quantum theory both as mediated by massless particles, which travel at the speed of light. In Newtonian gravity, the "speed" of gravity is instantaneous.